# How to filter numbers from a Table with Selenium/Serenity

Tags: serenity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTsBe.png)

How can I get only text and skip the numbers in the table?

`Xpath` now with numbers in Table:

```
public static Target WorkBaskets = PegaTarget.the("Werkbakken")
     .located(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@data-test-id,'20170818151525072438-R')and " + VISIBLE + "]"));
```

what is the `XPATH`?
if without the numbers from table wanted?

Now it gets with numbers in the rows,
Wanted without the numbers in Table.